# Flink: how to understand how many instances of parallel operators exist?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a KeyedStream to shard a stream of events by key.  Each keyed stream will emit events that then need to be recombined with all other events from the other keyed operators to form a single graph that will exist in Flink state.

The graph then needs to be processed / searched and possibly emit events downstream.  I want the graph operator to be able to be horizontally scalable, i.e. each parallel operator to process a subset of the graph (but which will require each operator to have access to the whole of the graph). I'm interested in how I can spread the load across all parallel operators.

```
// key input events for processing by key
KeyedStream<MyEvent> keyedStream = myInputStream.keyBy(...);
// process each keyed input stream and produce output events that need to be combined into a graph
SingleOutputStreamOperator<MyGraphEvent> graphStream = keyedStream.process(...));
// recombine into a single graph operator via broadcast(), then process
DataStream<MyOutputEvent> output = graphStream.broadcast().flatMap(new MyGraphFlatmapFunction());
```

I think I can use `broadcast()` to ensure that all outputs from each of the keyed operators is sent to every downstream operator.

`MyGraphFlatmapFunction` takes a stream of `MyGraphEvent` objects, creates a graph inside internal state and optionally produces a stream of `MyOutputEvent` objects.  I want each parallel operator to process a subset of the graph.  Irrespective of the number of parallel instances of the operator exist, I'd like for all of the graph to be processed (meaning I don't want each operator to just process some random subset of the graph) and I don't want to have parallel operators process the same part of the graph (no duplicate processing).

I'd like to be able to do something within `MyGraphFlatmapFunction` like:

```
int index;
// I want to get the operator instance number & the number of parallel operators in the stream topology
int operatorIndex = getOperatorIndex();
int operatorCount = getTotalNumberOfParallelOperators();
// process every nth object
for (index = 0; index < someCollection.size(); index++) {
    if (index % operatorCount == operatorIndex) {
        // do some processing
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Is there a way of knowing how many instances of the parallel operator exist and which operator this is?  Is there another way of achieving what I'm after?

Answer (score 3):

If you use a `RichFlatMapFunction`, you get access to the `RuntimeContext` via `getRuntimeContext()`. The `RuntimeContext` has the two methods you need:

- getNumberOfParallelSubtasks()
- getIndexOfThisSubtask()

Hope this helps.